# Inserting iframe inside html

Tags: php, html, iframe

i have this code in my index.php page:

```
$page->html .= "    ";
```

I want to put an iframe inside the " " to show correctly, but i have tried several ways and it dont work. Can you help me?
I tried this:

```
$page->html .= "<Iframe src="/shoutcast20/index.php" width="670" height="389" frameborder="0"></Iframe> ";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1-st solution

```
$page->html .= '<Iframe src="/shoutcast20/index.php" width="670" height="389" frameborder="0"></Iframe> ';
```

2-nd solution:

```
$page->html .= "<Iframe src=\"/shoutcast20/index.php\" width=\"670\" height=\"389\" frameborder=\"0\"></Iframe> ";
```

^^ Try
You need to put backslash before quotes or change double qoute to single qoute